# Balloon tip has different visual style when text fits on one line

Tags: winforms, notifyicon, balloon-tip

I have a WinForms app that makes use of a few [notify icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon(v=vs.110).aspx) which show [balloon tips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160065(v=vs.110).aspx) in various scenarios.

I've noticed ([as have others](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c103fe65-2a41-411d-9cb8-f7de378ea640/notifyicon-showballoontip-renders-balloon-tip-in-2-different-styles-in-vista?forum=winforms)...in 2008) that the visual style of the balloon tip is different when the `BalloonTipText` fits on a single line - it reverts to a style that I seem to remember from the days of Windows XP!

See below for a couple of examples...

[image: Single line of text]

[image: Multiple lines of text]

The code that does this is no more complex than:

```
someNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
someNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "A balloon tip";
someNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "One or multiple lines of text";
someNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(5000);
```

Without adding a second line, how can I ensure that the balloon tip always has the second style (square corners)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the .NET wrapper for NotifyIcon and it's contained BalloonTip does not allow for this. Quite why it picks the old style for one line and the new style for more lines I don't know.

If you really need to achieve this, you need to show the balloon with the Win32 message, making sure to set the balloon style in `dwInfoFlags` in the `NOTIFYICONDATA` structure. You can find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773352%28VS.85%29.aspx).

It's a fair old faff though, especially considering I suspect most end users would never notice!